# Android com.android.gallery3d doesn't compile

Tags: android, compilation, gallery

You can find the git repository [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery2).

After cloning, I get a lot of errors of unfound classes, like BasicDream, BasicTexture, BitmapUtils and others.

**How can I fix the project so it will compile?**

Comment: I added the v13 support library - resolving some of the errors

Comment: I then added a source folder: gallerycommon/src - resolving more erros.

Comment: Then added the folder src_pd as a source folder

Comment: Now I'm stuck with more resoution errors, like *android.util.LongSparseArray*, *com.android.camera.Util* and others.

Comment: Why is there a dependency with *com.android.camera.Util*? The camera should be a different app!

Comment: Builtin apps do not necessarily compile with the sdk, outside of the platform build where they are normally compiled.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, I did get all the android source code and it does not compile either. I started from a naive questions and gotten to the point of *why make it so difficult for developers to take an example from the built-in apps*? The built-in apps should be the rule - not the exception.

Comment: When this came up a few years ago, the explanation was that the built-ins predated the finalization of the sdk, and had not been reworked to use only public (as in exported) functionality from the final released sdk.  Not sure if that would apply in something that sounds like it was written more recently though.